Argo CD ApplicationSet: Conditional AutoSync for Dev and Manual Sync for Prod
I’m trying to set up an Argo CD ApplicationSet where I want to enable auto-sync for the develop environment and disable it for the prod environment. Here’s what I have so far:
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: my-application-deployment
spec:
  goTemplate: true
  goTemplateOptions: ["missingkey=error"]
  generators:
  - list:
      elements:
      - env: develop
        namespace: dev-my-service
        sync: true
      - env: prod
        namespace: my-service
        sync: false
  template:
    metadata:
      name: 'my-service-{{.env}}'
    spec:
      project: default
      source:
        repoURL: 'https://example.com/my-repo.git'
        targetRevision: develop
        path: 'my-service'
        helm:
          valueFiles:
          - 'values-{{.env}}.yaml'
      destination:
        name: in-cluster
        namespace: '{{.namespace}}'
      syncPolicy:
        syncOptions:
          - CreateNamespace=true
        {{- if .sync }}
        automated:
          prune: true
          selfHeal: true
        {{- end }}

However, it seems that Argo CD doesn’t support conditions in go-template for the syncPolicy field. When I try to apply this manifest, I get an error:
error splitting YAML to string: failed to unmarshal manifest: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 36: could not find expected ':' 
Thanks in advance!

A kubernetes manifest must be valid YAML (or JSON). What you show in your question is not. ArgoCD can support templating in values because it parses those after the manifest has been parsed by kubernetes.

A better way to achive your goal might be to create separate apps or appsets in Argo for development and production. Then you can set auto-sync for one but not for the other, either by hard-coding it, or by using something like Kustomize to patch the config for each specific environment.
